# Android Studio Javascript Import

Tags: javascript, android, implementation

**Hey I have this Code:**

```
//Set frame rate;
var fps = 30;

//Set size of canvas bitmap.
//(We set it lower than the screen resolution to improve 
//performance and make it 1.5 x wider than the screen 
//so objects can disappear off the screen cleanly).
var bmpW=1.5*480, bmpH=800;

//Init physics variables.
var gravity = 4/bmpH;
var impulse = 35/bmpH;

//Init background image variables.
var backGroundX = 0;
var backGroundShift = 6/bmpW;

//Init bird variables.
var charX=0.25, charY=0.3;
var charW=0.18, charH=0.18;
var flap=0; charSpeedY=0;
var angle=0;

//Init pillar variables.
//(We set speeds to a multiple of the width of one pixel
//which gives nice smooth (non flickering) motion.
var capHeight=0.08, gap=0.38, donePass=false;
var pill1X=1.3, pill1Y=0, pill1W=0.14, pill1H=0.4;
var pill2X=1.3, pill2Y=0.6, pill2W=0.14, pill2H=0.5;
var pillars=0, pillarSpeed=7/bmpW;

//Called when application is started.
function OnStart()
{
    //Lock screen orientation to Landscape and
    //stop screen turning off while playing.
    app.SetOrientation( "Portrait" );
    app.PreventScreenLock( true );

    //Create the main layout.
    lay = app.CreateLayout("Absolute", "FillXY" ); 

    //Create our scene layout.
    //(This layout is 1.5 times wider than the screen)
    layScene = app.CreateLayout( "Absolute" ); 
    layScene.SetPosition( -0.25,0, 1.5, 1 );
    lay.AddChild( layScene );

    //Create an blank image to act as our drawing canvas.
    var sw = app.GetScreenWidth();
    canvas = app.CreateImage( null, 1.5, 1.0, "fix", bmpW, bmpH );
    canvas.SetAutoUpdate( false );
    canvas.SetPaintColor( "#ff2222" );
    canvas.SetOnTouchDown( canvas_OnTouchMove );
    layScene.AddChild( canvas );

    //Create a background image in memory (not added to layout).
    imgBackground = app.CreateImage("/Sys/Img/Sky.jpg");

    //Create our character images in memory.
    imgFlapUp = app.CreateImage( "/Sys/Img/Eagle1.png" );
    imgFlapDown = app.CreateImage( "/Sys/Img/Eagle2.png" );
    imgCharDead = app.CreateImage( "/Sys/Img/Splat.png" );
    imgChar = imgFlapUp;

    //Create our pillar images in memory.
    imgPillarTop = app.CreateImage( "/Sys/Img/PillarTop.png" );
    imgPillar = app.CreateImage( "/Sys/Img/Pillar.png" );

    //Create Synth synthCrashect for flying sounds.
    synthFly = app.CreateSynth( "VCA,VCF" );
    synthFly.SetWaveShape( "White" );
    synthFly.SetVca( 260, 230, 0.08, 100 ); 
    synthFly.SetVcf( 340, 510, 0.26, 210, 500, 0.45 ); 
    synthFly.SetVolume( 0.9, 0.9 );

    //Create Synth object for passing pillar sounds.
    synthPass = app.CreateSynth( "VCA,VCF" );
    synthPass.SetWaveShape( "Square" );
    synthPass.SetVca( 10, 400, 0.8, 100 );
    synthPass.SetVcf( 10, 400, 0.8, 100, 1000, 0.85, 2.0 ); 

    //Create Synth object for collision sounds.
    synthCrash = app.CreateSynth( "VCA,VCF" );
    synthCrash.SetWaveShape( "White" );
    synthCrash.SetVca( 0, 130, 0, 0 ); 
    synthCrash.SetVcf( 110, 870, 0.45, 450, 2000, 0.4 ); 

    //Create a 'Start Again' button. 
    btn = app.CreateButton( "Start Again", 0.5, 0.1 ); 
    btn.SetPosition( 0.24,  0.5 );
    btn.SetVisibility( "Gone" );
    btn.SetOnTouch( btnStart_OnTouch ); 
    lay.AddChild( btn ); 

    //Add layout to app.    
    app.AddLayout( lay );

    //Switch off debugging for max performance.
    app.SetDebugEnabled( false );

    //Drawing the game frame 30x a second.
    //(Slow this down if you get black flashes)
    timer = setInterval( DrawFrame, 1000/fps );
    gameOver = false;
}

//Update and redraw all game graphics.
function DrawFrame()
{
    //Clear the canvas.
    canvas.Clear();

    //Draw two copies of the background image side by side.
    canvas.DrawImage( imgBackground, backGroundX, 0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    canvas.DrawImage( imgBackground, 1.0 + backGroundX, 0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //Shift the background images left slightly each frame
    //until the left image is off screen, then we start again.
    backGroundX -= backGroundShift;
    if( backGroundX <= -1 ) backGroundX = 0;

    //Move the bird and limit it's vertical range.
    charY += charSpeedY;
    charSpeedY += gravity;
    if( charY > 0.85 ) charY = 0.85;
    else if( charY < -0.1 ) charY = -0.1;

    //Adjust an limit bird's angle.
    if( angle < 45 ) angle += 3;
    if( charY >= 0.85 ) angle -= 30;
    if( angle < 0 ) angle = 0;

    //Draw our bird.
    if( flap < 2 ) imgChar = imgFlapUp;
    else if( flap > 2 ) imgChar = imgFlapDown;
    canvas.DrawImage( imgChar, charX,charY, charW,-1, angle );
    if( flap > 4 ) flap = 0; else flap++;

    //Change top pillar's height every time it goes off screen.
    if( pill1X <= 0 ) {
         pill1H = 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.5;
         donePass = false;
    } 

    //Move and draw pillar 1.
    if( pill1X <= 0 ) pill1X = 1.0; 
    else pill1X -= pillarSpeed;
    canvas.DrawImage( imgPillar, pill1X, pill1Y, pill1W, pill1H-capHeight );
    canvas.DrawImage( imgPillarTop, pill1X, pill1H-capHeight, pill1W, capHeight );

    //Move and draw pillar 2.
    if( pill2X <= 0 ) pill2X = 1.0; 
    else pill2X -= pillarSpeed;
    pill2Y = pill1H + gap;
    canvas.DrawImage( imgPillarTop, pill2X, pill2Y, pill2W, capHeight, 180 );
    canvas.DrawImage( imgPillar, pill2X, pill2Y+capHeight, pill2W, pill2H );

    //Check for collisions by comparing x and y coordinates.
    hit1 = IsCollision( charX,charY,charW,charH, pill1X,pill1Y,pill1W,pill1H, 0.06 );
    hit2 = IsCollision( charX,charY,charW,charH, pill2X,pill2Y,pill2W,pill2H, 0.06 ); 

    //Deal with collisions.
    if( hit1 || hit2 ) GameOver();

    //Play little tune if we pass a pillar.
    if( charX > pill1X+pill1W && !donePass ) 
        PassedPillar();

    //Draw the score.
    canvas.SetTextSize( 11 );
    canvas.DrawText( pillars, 0.77, 0.04 );

    //Update the canvas.
    canvas.Update();
}

//Handle touching the screen.
function canvas_OnTouchMove( ev )
{
    //Reverse direction of bird.
    charSpeedY = -impulse;
    angle = 0;

    //Play flying sound.
    if( !gameOver) 
        synthFly.PlayTone( 0, 3000 );
}

//Check for a collision between two objects.
//(d is the depth of impact required)
function IsCollision( x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2, d )
{
    if( x2 < x1+w1-d && x2+w2 > x1+d && 
            y2+h2 > y1+d && y2 < y1+h1-d )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Handle passing a pillar.
function PassedPillar()
{
    //Play a little tune.
    synthPass.SetNoteLength( 1.5 );
    synthPass.PlayMidiTune( " 65:32, 70:32, 76:32" );
    donePass = true;

    //Count pillars passed.
    pillars++;

    //Shrink pillar gap each time.
    gap -= 0.005;
}

//Handle 'game over' situation.
function GameOver()
{
    //Draw dead character and play sound.
    imgChar = imgCharDead;
    canvas.DrawImage( imgChar, charX,charY, charW,charH );
    synthFly.Stop();
    synthCrash.PlayTone( 0, 1000 );

    //Show message and start button.
    canvas.SetTextSize( 18 );
    canvas.DrawText( "Game Over!", 0.3, 0.48 );
    btn.SetVisibility( "Show" );

    //Stop drawing frames.
    clearInterval( timer );
    gameOver = true;
}

//Called when user touches 'Start Again' button. 
function btnStart_OnTouch() 
{ 
    //Reset bird and pillar positions etc.
    charY=0.3;  angle=0;  charSpeedY=0;
    pill1X=1.3;  pill2X=1.3; pillars=0; gap=0.38;
    pillarSpeed=7/bmpW;

    //Hide start button.
    btn.SetVisibility( "Gone" );

    //Start drawing frames again.
    gameOver = false;
    timer = setInterval( DrawFrame, 1000/fps );
}
```

And my Question now is, how to implement the code that it works in Android studio when I copy this in Android Studio it doesn't work. I have to try to rewrite it but it doesn't work :(

So Thanks

Comment: this is not java code

Comment: What is it then???

Comment: Oh. Can I import it to android Studio??

Comment: I don't know. Changing the question's tag to "javascript" might attract people who are able to answer. But tbh, you should really research that yourself first.